# GetContact() throws the error "You do not have permission to perform that action", it previously worked

Tags: google-apps-script

I created a Google Apps Script months ago, it was running without any errors until today, without changing any code, it is throwing the error "You do not have permission to perform that action." when trying to run the line below

```
ContactsApp.getContact('name@email.com');
```

I've tried revoking my permissions to this script, ran it again, so they are refreshed, ensuring that I have allowed access to the contacts Application properly, but this does not help.  I've also tried deleting cookies and cache to no avail.  Our admins also inform me there has been no changes to permissions.  Any advice would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Stumble on this problem today, found fix:
open your script
go to "Resources/Extended Google Services"
you will find there message like "This services also must be enabled in Developer console"
folow link, find "Contacts API" and set it to "ON"

Comment: Advanced Google Services?

Comment: by default my Script editor showing Ukrainian UI and it`s say "Розширені служби Google" which translate as "Extended Google services", so it`s possible you have there "Advanced"

Comment: Thank you, this solution worked!  The menu was "Resources/Advanced Google Services" however.  Thank you for the help.